# check riak connection when rails starts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, riak

I'm using rails4, ruby2.2
My rails project stores some values in riak from different controllers. So, i want to check riak connection, when rails starts. If riak fails, rails has to redirect to login page. Please help me

I tried the below in application_controller.rb

```
if riak.ping
   redirect_to signin_path, :error => "Riak down"
end
```

But it shows an error like
ActionController::RoutingError - undefined local variable or method `signin_path' for ApplicationController:Class:

Answer (score 1):

Just put your code to `before_action` and check your URL helper (may be it should be `sign_in_path`):

```
before_action :check_riak

def check_riak
    if riak.ping
       redirect_to signin_path, :error => "Riak down"
    end
end
```